Understanding audio input filtering on Bluetooth transmitter module
I'm currently reverse engineering the circuit of an off-the-shelf Bluetooth transmitter module (Scosche FlyTunes), in particular the audio input section. The attached schematic picture is what I have gathered by looking at and measuring the circuit on the carrier PCB, between the audio input (3.5mm plug going into the headphone jack of the source) and the Bluetooth SoC module doing the A/D conversion and wireless transmission.

I would like to understand what each component does, how the values are picked, and why some have been left out. I've labeled the components on one of the audio channels, the other channel is identical.  R0 and C3 are not populated. C1 seems to be 100pF (measured after drawing). Audio GND really does go to the general ground plane without further filtering.
For example, does it help if I think of R1 and R2 as a resistive divider?
Or is R1+C1 a RC a high-pass filter and R2+C2 a RC low-pass filter?
How to think of R3 and C4 in series? What would the role of C3 have been if it was added?
I will be thankful for any explanation, as well as resources to further understand this kind of audio circuit design!

Because R3 is labelled as 5k5 (when it should more realistically be 5k5 || 2k4), it's either a drawing mistake by you or, the interface chip inside the Bluetooth module needs to be revealed and have a data sheet available.

@Andyaka can you elaborate? 5k5 || 2k4 meaning those two resistors in parallel? Why? To somehow match R1 and R2? Would be great to have some background to your reasoning.. thanks!
